# Swift buttons hidden fatal error: Array index out of range

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, hidden, fatal-error

```
 @IBAction func endTurn(sender: UIButton) {

    let index: Int = Int (arc4random_uniform(UInt32(coins.count)))
        var i = Int(arc4random_uniform((3)))
        for i; i < 3; i++ {

            coins[i].hidden = true
            coins.removeAtIndex(i)
            println(i)
        }
    }
```

I have 21 coins. It's array of buttons (@IBOutlet var coins: [UIButton]!). When i press "endTurn", the coins hidden. But when i have 3 coins or less, i get the fatal error (the line: coins[i].hidden = true). 
What i need do? 
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access an index of the array that is out of bounds. So adding a check that the `i` is in the range of the array should prevent a crash.

```
if(i < coins.length) {
   coins[i].hidden = true
   coins.removeAtIndex(i)
}
```

An array with 3 elements [0, 1, 2] goes from index 0-2 (the first index of an array is 0).

Answer (score 2):

Removing from an array while you iterate through it is a big no-no and probably not doing what you want it to.

```
var i = 0
var arr = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

for i; i < 3; i++ {
    arr.removeAtIndex(i)
}

print(arr)
```

prints ["2", "4"]
Because if you look at the code, you remove at index 0, so your array is now ["2", "3", "4"], then you increment i, and remove at index 1. Since the array shifted, index 1 is "3", and you are skipping over "2".

Use this information in conjunction with the other answers

Answer (score 0):

This loop:

```
for i; i < 3; i++ {
    coins[i].hidden = true
    coins.removeAtIndex(i) // <-- here
    println(i)
}
```

On every iteration you delete a coin. So you can delete up to 3 coins in total, when `arc4random_uniform` returns 0. When you have 3 (or fewer) coins left, you are bound to run into an index out of range problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an `Array Concurrent Modification`. And it's dangerous.

You should not modify the `length` of an array while you are iterating it. You could end up in a scenario where you are accessing the element at an index that no longer exists.

Let Swift solve the problem for you with the `removeRange` method. The following snippet should show you how to fix your code.

```
var animals = ["dog", "cat", "duck", "eagle", "cow"]
let from = 1
let to = 2
for i in from...to {
    println(i) // will print `1` and `2`
}
animals.removeRange(from...to) // -> ["dog", "eagle", "cow"]
```

Hope this helps.